Basic ABP Project - Deployed to Server IIS - Index page generates a 404 error
I'm trying ABP and created a new solution using the guide.  Everything works great locally with the base project but when I deployed to my IIS Server (on aws), the home page has a 404 error.
I've configured the selfurl to match the site url. copied the pfx to the root folder, change apppool to use LoadUserProfile to True.
Here's the log
2024-04-06 03:10:59.852 -07:00 [INF] Content root path: E:\inetpu\bAbpDemo\2024-04-06B
2024-04-06 03:10:59.875 -07:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://abpdemo.test.com/ - null null
2024-04-06 03:11:02.854 -07:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://abpdemo.test.com/ - 302 null null 2979.501ms
2024-04-06 03:11:02.857 -07:00 [INF] Request reached the end of the middleware pipeline without being handled by application code. Request path: GET https://abpdemo.test.com/, Response status code: 302
2024-04-06 03:11:03.112 -07:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://abpdemo.test.com/Error?httpStatusCode=404 - null null

[404 Error on the body of the page](https://i.sstatic.net/uzRxQ.png)


There is no way to solve the problem based on these error messages alone, try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.
